# working with arrays in jinja2

Tags: python, arrays, jinja2

I'm passing an array object from a view in my Flask server to the jinja2 template. Let's say the name is `aList`. When I try to change a value inside of `aList` like this:

in Flask:

```
aList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

in the template:

```
{% set aList[0] = "work, dammit!" %}
```

I get this error that tells me that "=" is expected instead of "[" in the template.

Can someone tell what the right way of working with arrays is in jinja2?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: Logic should not be handled in the template!

Second: If you really have to:

If jinja does not accept the array syntax you should be able to work around it by using `operator.setitem` from the stdlib. (Be sure to add `operator` to globals)

```
{% set foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] %}
{% set _ = operator.setitem(foo, 'some stuff') %}
{{ foo }}
```

Comment: and how / where do we do this? "Be sure to add operator to globals"

Comment: Wherever you set up your jinja environment.

Comment: Why have flow controls, conditional logic, operators at all then? Helm, Ansible, SaltStack all implement logic. Do handle logic in templates. Carefully.

Comment: @NomenNescio to be able to factorize similar templates together and avoid duplication (and errors!).